# Debian Testing installs Iceweasel ESR (severely outdated)?

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, apt-get, iceweasel

I just reinstalled Debian Testing, and for some reason, instead of Iceweasel 25, I have 17. The installed and candidate versions are both `17.0.9esr-1~deb7u1`. `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` does nothing, and it seems that version 17 is the latest for this install. I was on Debian Testing before, and Iceweasel was at the latest version. Even Debian Stable had an Iceweasel version >20. Why would it be trying to install ESR now?

Answer (score 0):

Checking [Debian's package database](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=iceweasel), Iceweasel 25 is only listed in the **experimiental** release channel, even **unstable** has only version 24:

```
jessie (testing) (web): Webbrowser auf Basis von Firefox 
17.0.9esr-1~deb7u1: amd64 armel armhf i386 ia64 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 mips mipsel powerpc s390x sparc 
sid (unstable) (web): Webbrowser auf Basis von Firefox 
24.1.0esr-1: amd64 armel i386 ia64 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 mips mipsel powerpc s390x sparc 
24.0-2: armhf 
17.0.8esr-2: hurd-i386 
17.0.7esr-1 [debports]: ppc64 
10.0.12esr-1+nmu1 [debports]: powerpcspe 
3.5.18-1 [debports]: hppa 
2.0.0.12-1 [debports]: m68k 
experimental (rc-buggy) (web): Webbrowser auf Basis von Firefox 
25.0-1: amd64 armel armhf i386 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 mips powerpc s390x 
25.0~b9-1: sparc
```

Perhaps you added the experimental repository manually in your previous testing installation?!

Comment: I used a fork of Debian before, so it's possible that the distro's repos had the newer version, but I'm 100% positive I didn't have experimental or unstable in my last install. I found `http://mozilla.debian.net/`, which tells you what to do to install any version on any release.